# .Net MAUI - How to change the image shown as you drag from the source to the target?

Tags: drag-and-drop, maui

I'm working on a UI in .Net MAUI that uses drag and drop.  The drag and drop is not a problem; works fine.  The issue is that I want to change the image show as I drag it around.  Not the drag source nor the drop target, but the image that follows the cursor.

The example below shows the behavior.  I want to change it so that the image that is moving with the cursor is different.

If I had two wishes for Christmas, it would be to hide the "Copy" tooltip-esq graphic that MAUI puts on top of my image as I drag it.

XAML

```
<Frame Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" BorderColor="LightBlue" ZIndex="1" MaximumWidthRequest="400" MaximumHeightRequest="400" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <Image x:Name="reds"  Source="reds_trans_bg.png" MaximumHeightRequest="100" MinimumHeightRequest="100" MaximumWidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <DragGestureRecognizer  CanDrag="True" DragStarting="DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting_2"  />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Frame>

<Frame Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" BorderColor="LightBlue" ZIndex="1" MaximumWidthRequest="400" MaximumHeightRequest="400" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropGestureRecognizer_Drop_2" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
        <Image Source="washer_trans_bg.png" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" ZIndex="100" MaximumWidthRequest="100" MaximumHeightRequest="100" >
        </Image>
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
            <Label x:Name="contents" Text="test" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold">
            </Label>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Code

```
private void DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting_2(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (sender as Element)?.Parent as Image;
    e.Data.Properties.Add("Text", "Red");
}

private void DropGestureRecognizer_Drop_2(object sender, DropEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.Properties["Text"].ToString();
    
    contents.Text = $"Red: {++count}";
}
```

[image: maui drag and drop example]

Comment: Beware Bing Chat - creative mode made up an answer when I asked "in .net maui drag from an image to a frame with a separate image as the drag visual c#" - it created a SetDragVisual method that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik the only platforms where you can do that out of the box are iOS and Mac catalyst.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=macios#enable-drag).

```cs
void OnDragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
{
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
    Func<UIKit.UIDragPreview> action = () =>
    {
        var image = UIKit.UIImage.FromFile("dotnet_bot.png");
        UIKit.UIImageView imageView = new UIKit.UIImageView(image);
        imageView.ContentMode = UIKit.UIViewContentMode.Center;
        imageView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
        return new UIKit.UIDragPreview(imageView);
    };

    e.PlatformArgs.SetPreviewProvider(action);
#endif
}
```